calculate a coordinate of a graph
I want to calculate one of the coordinates of a point using defined quantities and mathematical functions.
In my case, I want to draw an arrow connecting the initial point with coordinates (0, -log Ca), but I can't calculate the ordinate -log Ca with Ca a parameter.
How do I program this coordinate calculation?
\documentclass[border=0.2cm,11pt,convert={ghostscript,outext=.png,density=800x800}]{standalone}%conversion en png avec ghostscript

%COMPILé AVEC XeLaTeX

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mathcode`\.="013B%virgule décimale en mode math
%\usepackage{tikz}% chargé automatiquement par pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={~},use comma}
\usepackage{siunitx}% unités et écriture de valeurs

\begin{document}
    
\footnotesize

    % définitions des grandeurs chimiques :
    \def\Ke{1e-14}% produit ionique de l'eau
    \def\Ca{0.015}
    \def\Va{10.0} % volume d'acide (mL)
    \def\Cb{0.010}
    %---------------------------------------
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Veq}{\Ca*\Va/\Cb}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[% mise en forme du graphique :
    xmin=0,xmax=25,
    ymin=0,ymax=14,
    xlabel=volume $ V_b $ versé (mL),
    ylabel=pH,
    ytick distance=2,
    minor y tick num=1,% nombre de graduations secondaires intermédiaires
    minor x tick num=4,% nombre de graduations secondaires intermédiaires
    grid,
    grid=both,% grilles primaire et secondaire
    title=titrage pH-métrique d'un acide fort,
    axis line shift=3pt,
    xtick align=outside,
    ytick align=outside,
    tickpos=left,
    ]
        
    \coordinate (initial) at (0,$-log \Ca$);
    \draw[red, ->] (2,$-log \Ca +2$) -- (initial);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\pgfmathsetmacro{\NegativeLogCa}{-log10(\Ca)}% should give you what the value of -log_10 \Ca.
